# Uncaught ReferenceError: define is not defined iframeResizer.contentWindow.js

Tags: javascript, iframe-resizer

Trying to make an `iframe` with a dynamic `height`. I know the question been raised before, but I can't get this to work.

I have a *WordPress* site, with a `form` i am trying to `iframe` on another, *non-WordPress* site.

On the website I have enqueued `iframeResizer.contentWindow.js`

My page with the `iframe` looks like this:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src="mysite.com/iframeResizer.js">
<style>iframe{width: 1px;min-width: 100%;}</style>
<iframe id="myIframe" src="https://testsite.com/test-form" scrolling="no"></iframe>
<script>iFrameResize({log:true, checkOrigin: false}, '#myIframe')</script>
```

However, this doesn't work.

In console i get this:

```
[iFrameSizer][Host page: myIframe] IFrame scrolling disabled for myIframe
[iFrameSizer][Host page: myIframe] [init] Sending msg to iframe[myIframe] 
(myIframe:8:false:true:32:true:true:null:bodyOffset:null:null:0:false:parent:scroll) targetOrigin: *

Uncaught ReferenceError: define is not defined
    at iframeResizer.contentWindow.js:1121
    at iframeResizer.contentWindow.js:1125
```

I can see the `iframeResizer.contentWindow.js` file in my `iframe`.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using the 'uncompiled' version of the code. Either use the files from https://github.com/davidjbradshaw/iframe-resizer/tree/master/js or use the files from one of the CDNs listed in the readme: https://github.com/davidjbradshaw/iframe-resizer#cdns